# Maximise size of shape (Have I solved this right?)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**The task was:**

We want to make windows for a house whose bottom part is a rectangle and top part is a semicircle whose 'bottom' matches the length of the rectangle's top. The perimeter of such a window is given, it's 4 meters. How should we choose the sizes for the window to maximise the amount of light they let in (so to maximise their area).
*((( I hope I explained the task well enough, it was rather hard for me as I am not native in English )))*

**My solution:**

Let's name the sides of the rectangle $a$ and $b$. To avoid confusion, let the 'bottom and top' be $a$ and the other two sides $b$. Then the semicircle's radius has to be $\frac{1}{2}a$. Thus, the semicircle's perimeter is $\frac{1}{2} \left[ 2 \left( \frac{1}{2}a \right) \pi \right] = \frac{1}{2}a\pi$. Then, the perimeter of the whole shape is:
$$ K = a+2b+\frac{1}{2}a\pi = 4$$
We rearrange this to express $b$:
$$ b = a \left( -\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\pi \right)+2$$
I can define the area of the shape in terms of $a$ and $b$ (I define a function $T$ that takes variables $a$ and $b$)
$$ T(a,b) = ab + \frac{1}{2} \left( \left( \frac{1}{2}a \right)^2 \pi\right) = ab + \frac{1}{8}a^2\pi =ab + a^2 \left( \frac{\pi}{8}\right)$$
Then I plug in $b$ into this formula, so I get a function that takes only one variable (that is $a$) *Side note: I am doing this because my current knowledge of Maths allows me to only differentiate single-variable functions*
$$ T(a) = a \left[ a \left( -\frac{1}{4}\pi-\frac{1}{2} \right) + 2 \right] + a^2 \frac{\pi}{8}$$
$$ T(a) = a^2 \left( -\frac{1}{4}\pi-\frac{1}{2} \right) + 2a + a^2 \frac{\pi}{8}$$
For easier calculation, I set
$C:=\left( -\frac{1}{4}\pi-\frac{1}{2} \right)$ and $D:= \frac{\pi}{8}$. Then:
$$T(a)=a^2(C)+a^2(D)+2a$$
I can easily differentiate this:
$$ T'(a)=2a(C)+2a(D)+2 = 2a \left( C+D\right)+2$$
To find the maximum values of the function, I look for the zeroes of its derivative:
$$ 2a \left( C+D\right)+2 = 0$$
$$ a=-\frac{1}{C+D}$$
I plug back $C$ and $D$:
$$ a=-\frac{1}{\left( -\frac{1}{4}\pi-\frac{1}{2} \right)+\frac{\pi}{8}}=-\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{8}\pi - \frac{1}{2}} \approx 1.1202$$
Thus,
$$ b \approx 0.5601$$

**Is this correct? I am very unsure.**

Comment: At what part are you unsure about? It looks alright to me (I haven't checked all the algebra). I would, however, check that the second derivative at the point you found is negative, so that you actually found the maximum area, not min.

Comment: I have not checked your results, but your reasoning is correct.

Comment: @grixor I don't know, I feel like I've made a mistake somewhere in the exercise, but if it looks all right, then... And yes, I forgot to check that, true. But what if I find that I found the minimum?

Comment: @grixor Considering it's a parabola there can only be one extreme, and that extreme must be a maximum. Otherwise you'd be able to have arbitrary area.

Comment: @orlp Well yes, but I think for a complete solution we need to mention either that it's a parabola, or check the second derivative, don't we?

Comment: @bertalanp99 In Mathematica, or wolframalpha, 
   FindMaximum[{a*b + a^2*Pi/8, a + 2 b + 1/2 a Pi == 4 }, {a, b}] 
yields what you got!

Comment: @grixor Of course, I should have checked there... Thanks

Comment: $T(a)$ is a downward vertical parabola, so what you found is the maximum. To check it, just compute the two "zeros" of the parabola, and see if the $a$ you found is in he middle. (by the way you can group the coeff. of $a^2$ right from the beginning)

Comment: Additionally, for you to feel more comfortable, just from an intuitive point of view, consider that the figure that - given the perimeter - maximizes the area is a circle: you obtained a circle with "the bottom-half rectangularized".